# May one do the Mitzvah of Nichum Aveilim/Consoling Mourners on Tish'a B'av?

Tags: halacha, mourning-aveilus, tisha-bav

Based on [On Tish'a B'Av,can someone say the typical "Mourner's statement" to any/everyone else?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/61512/16354), may one perform the mitzvah of Nichum Aveilim for one who is sitting shiv'a on Tish'a B'av? Would it make a difference as to when during the day it was, or what the person was saying to console/comfort the mourner?

Comment: Interesting question. What seems a bit contradictory, is that Tish'a B'av is called a *mo'ed*. Yet, unlike any other *mo'ed*, it doesn't end aveilut / shiva.

Comment: Why would you think that one can't?

Comment: @Al Berko  Perhaps because all Israel are regarded as mourners on Tisha BeAv.

Comment: @Epicentre so what? Can mourners not console each other?

Comment: @DoubleAA maybe not https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/23248/759

Comment: @AlBerko maybe it can be considered to be sheilat shalom

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one is allowed to be מנחם אבלים at any time on Tisha B'av. Rabbi Nosson Gestetner explains, that from the fact that the tefillah of Nacheim is said in Shemone Esrei on Tisha B'av,  we can derive that there is no Issur to accept condolences- ניחום on Tisha B'av. And even though we only say it in Shemone Esrei of Mincha (למנהג הרמ"א), someone who doesn't fast and has to Bentch Birkas Hamazon will say Nacheim then even if he eats at night (משמעות הרמ"א סימן תקנ"ז). This proves that at all times on Tisha B'av is one allowed to accept condolences.  שו"ת להורות נתן חלק י' (סימן נב אות ד)

Also see
ספר נחמת ישראל (סוף פרק לו) בשם הגר"ח קניבסקי זצוק"ל

Comment: What about offering condolences?